# Autolayout Constraint Stack Trace iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, stack-trace, crash-reports

I'm getting the stack trace below reported by a crash report.

The only point my app is involved is the app entrance in line 60. It seems to be triggered by an observer (line 54) but since everything else is thrown from internal frameworks, I'm not sure how to go about it.

I'd really appreciate anything that could lead me to the right track.

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x181192e38 __exceptionPreprocess + 124 (NSException.m:162)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1807f7f80 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:531)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x181192d80 +[NSException raise:format:] + 120 (NSException.m:140)
3   Foundation                      0x181acade0 -[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression setPriorityVector:forKnownAbsentVariable:] + 88 (NSISObjectiveLinearExpression.m:168)
4   Foundation                      0x181c474d4 __128-[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression replaceVariable:withExpression:processVariableNewToReceiver:processVariableDroppedFromReceiver:]_block_invoke + 308 (NSISObjectiveLinearExpression.m:298)
5   Foundation                      0x181ac7cc8 -[NSISLinearExpression enumerateVariablesAndCoefficients:] + 284 (NSISLinearExpression.m:689)
6   Foundation                      0x181acb108 -[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression replaceVariable:withExpression:processVariableNewToReceiver:processVariableDroppedFromReceiver:] + 352 (NSISObjectiveLinearExpression.m:275)
7   Foundation                      0x181ac8d18 -[NSISEngine substituteOutAllOccurencesOfBodyVar:withExpression:] + 600 (NSISEngine.m:433)
8   Foundation                      0x181acb928 -[NSISEngine pivotToMakeBodyVar:newHeadOfRowWithHead:andDropRow:] + 340 (NSISEngine.m:495)
9   Foundation                      0x181ac9648 -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 168 (NSISEngine.m:774)
10  Foundation                      0x181acc1f8 -[NSISEngine tryUsingArtificialVariableToAddConstraintWithMarker:rowBody:usingInfeasibilityHandlingBehavior:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 264 (NSISEngine.m:1344)
11  Foundation                      0x181ac797c -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 616 (NSISEngine.m:1850)
12  Foundation                      0x181ac75cc -[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 284 (NSLayoutConstraint.m:1410)
13  Foundation                      0x181ac51c8 -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 228 (NSLayoutConstraint.m:1447)
14  UIKit                           0x1863e1958 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 468 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:614)
15  UIKit                           0x1863e1728 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraintWithoutUpdatingConstraintsArray:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 72 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:639)
16  UIKit                           0x1863e15d0 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 288 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:668)
17  UIKit                           0x186ac679c __69-[_UILayoutArrangement _updateCanvasConnectionConstraintsIfNecessary]_block_invoke + 336 (_UILayoutArrangement.m:879)
18  UIKit                           0x186ac6208 -[_UILayoutArrangement _updateCanvasConnectionConstraintsIfNecessary] + 804 (_UILayoutArrangement.m:916)
19  UIKit                           0x186ac4cd4 -[_UILayoutArrangement _updateArrangementConstraints] + 96 (_UILayoutArrangement.m:597)
20  UIKit                           0x1866c0f10 -[_UIAlignedLayoutArrangement _updateArrangementConstraints] + 56 (_UIAlignedLayoutArrangement.m:485)
21  UIKit                           0x1863e2010 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 384 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3290)
22  UIKit                           0x1868f1f0c __32-[UIStackView updateConstraints]_block_invoke + 56 (UIStackView.m:284)
23  UIKit                           0x186b72ad8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 168 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3100)
24  UIKit                           0x1868f1ec0 -[UIStackView updateConstraints] + 80 (UIStackView.m:283)
25  UIKit                           0x186b72f98 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 460 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3182)
26  UIKit                           0x186b73200 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 200 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3223)
27  UIKit                           0x186b72ec8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 252 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3169)
28  Foundation                      0x181ac4d50 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168 (NSISEngine.m:1720)
29  UIKit                           0x1863e4c80 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 64 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3089)
30  UIKit                           0x186b731d4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 156 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3219)
31  UIKit                           0x1863e5b64 __60-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 100 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3237)
32  Foundation                      0x181ac4d50 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168 (NSISEngine.m:1720)
33  UIKit                           0x1863e4c80 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 64 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3089)
34  UIKit                           0x1863e5798 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 244 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3236)
35  UIKit                           0x18692d4d8 -[UITableViewCellContentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 200 (UITableViewCellContentView.m:96)
36  UIKit                           0x186b70b84 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:hasIntentionallyCollapsedHeight:] + 352 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:2371)
37  UIKit                           0x1867852f8 -[UITableViewCell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:] + 344 (UITableViewCell.m:1085)
38  UIKit                           0x186636c28 -[UITableView _heightForCell:atIndexPath:] + 392 (UITableView.m:12201)
39  UIKit                           0x18642b79c __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 2960 (UITableView.m:8101)
40  UIKit                           0x1862eb4b4 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 80 (UIView.m:9205)
41  UIKit                           0x18642abe8 -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 460 (UITableView.m:7978)
42  UIKit                           0x186632fa0 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 788 (UITableView.m:10605)
43  UIKit                           0x1866330a8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 80 (UITableView.m:10629)
44  UIKit                           0x1866221a8 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2360 (UITableView.m:2234)
45  UIKit                           0x186637b74 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 104 (UITableView.m:12373)
46  UIKit                           0x1863c87ac -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 176 (UITableView.m:7214)
47  UIKit                           0x1862d80e4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656 (UIView.m:11881)
48  QuartzCore                      0x183c7ea28 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148 (CALayer.mm:8899)
49  QuartzCore                      0x183c79634 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292 (CALayer.mm:8779)
50  QuartzCore                      0x183c794f4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32 (CALayer.mm:2524)
51  QuartzCore                      0x183c78b24 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252 (CAContextInternal.mm:1627)
52  QuartzCore                      0x183c7886c CA::Transaction::commit() + 512 (CATransactionInternal.mm:417)
53  UIKit                           0x1862ce4f8 _afterCACommitHandler + 180 (UIApplication.m:2425)
54  CoreFoundation                  0x1811487b0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1620)
55  CoreFoundation                  0x181146554 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:1716)
56  CoreFoundation                  0x181146984 __CFRunLoopRun + 928 (CFRunLoop.c:2558)
57  CoreFoundation                  0x181070d10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
58  GraphicsServices                0x182958088 GSEventRunModal + 180 (GSEvent.c:2245)
59  UIKit                           0x186345f70 UIApplicationMain + 204 (UIApplication.m:3772)
60  Thai                            0x100059d30 main + 628 (main.swift:14)
61  libdyld.dylib                   0x180c0e8b8 start + 4 (start_glue.s:78)
```